# How to force ag-grid to autoSizeAllColumns even if grid is not visible

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have tab layout with 3 tabs. Second one contains ag-grid. It looks somewhat like that `<custom-tab></custom-tab> <custom-tab><my-ag-grid></custom-tab> <custom-tab></custom-tab>`

ag-grid data is loaded at the moment of loading of whole layout. So if I call `autoSizeAllColumns()` for `rowDataUpdated` event of grid, it's called properly but autoSizeAllColumns() doesn't do anything because grid was invisible, as it's content of second tab. If I set `setTimeout(() => {autoSizeAllColumns(), 2000})` and I will manage to open second tab in 2 second, columns will be resized correctly. So the question is, how to force autoSizeColumns to work even if grid has data loaded, but is not visible yet?